# Alarmmanager & Soundpool - Android

Tags: android, audio, alarmmanager, soundpool

I'm doing an alarm System. The alarms are working OK, but the sound doesn't work.. I'm doing a little test and I don't understand where is the problem.. In the Alarm activity, I've the following code:

```
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    soundPool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    try {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = assetManager.openFd("sound.ogg");
        mySoundId = soundPool.load(descriptor, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"We've problem's!!, "
                + e.getMessage());
    }   

    soundPool.play(mySoundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```

There are not errors.. but music doesn't work.. Instead, if I program the PLAY in a bottom work's!! Can anyone help me please??

Comment: What does `soundPool.play()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code and found the problem. It is a common problem in SoundPool. You need to wait for the sound to finish loading before you play it. That's why `soundPool.play()` returned zero. The sound was not ready.

In API 8, [`setOnLoadCompleteListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setOnLoadCompleteListener%28android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener%29) was introduces which will solve the problem:

```
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,int status) {
       //play the sound.
    }
});
```

however, if you are targeting lower APIs, You can't tell for sure if your sound is ready to be played or not. In this case, I suggest you use [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Comment: If I remove the extension .ogg I've an excepcion :'(

Comment: Just to be sure, you removed it from the code, not from the actual file, right? :)